# How can I put/bind labels or paragraphs exactly on top of items?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I want to place these labels exactly on top of the items. I just tried to first put the `<ion-label>`. It is in deed on a top layer to the items but not top centered to them but on the left to them. What should I add so its on the top centered?  I wouldn't know any CSS I could apply here...
I added the `<ion-col>` but now my checkbox items aren't round anymore.[image]

```
 <ion-row>
     <ion-label>Global</ion-label>
       <ion-item mode="ios" lines="none">
         <ion-icon name="globe"></ion-icon>
           <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
       </ion-item>
      <ion-label>Lokal</ion-label>
        <ion-item mode="ios" lines="none">
          <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
            <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
      <ion-label>Mann</ion-label>
        <ion-item mode="ios" lines="none">
          <ion-icon name="male"></ion-icon>
            <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
       </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
```

CSS:

```
 @import "../../theme/mixins/checkbox-tag";
.checkbox-list {
  .checkbox-item {
    --padding-start: var(--page-margin);
    --padding-end: var(--page-margin);
    --inner-padding-end: 0px;



    ion-checkbox {
      margin-inline-end: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.checkbox-tags {
padding: 2%;


    @include checkbox-tag();

.checkbox-tag {
  padding: 4.5%;

}
```

CSS import:

```
@mixin checkbox-tag() {
    // Default values
    --checkbox-tag-color: #000;
    --checkbox-tag-background: #FFF;
    --checkbox-tag-active-color: #FFF;
    --checkbox-tag-active-background: #000;

      .checkbox-tag {
      // Reset values from Ionic (ion-item) styles
          --padding-start: 0px;
      --inner-padding-end: 8px;
          --inner-padding-start: 8px;
          --ion-item-background: var(--checkbox-tag-background);
      --ion-item-color: var(--checkbox-tag-color);

      &.rounded-tag {
              --border-radius: 2.2rem;
          }

          &.item-checkbox-checked {
        --ion-item-background: var(--checkbox-tag-active-background);
        --ion-item-color: var(--checkbox-tag-active-color);
          }



          .tag-label {
              margin: 5px;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.2px;
        text-align: center;
          }

          ion-checkbox {
              margin: 0px;
              // To hide the .checkbox-icon
              width: 0px;
              --border-width: 0px;
              height: 0px;
              // We cant set width and height for .checkbox-icon .checkbox-inner, so lets hide it changing its color
              --color-checked: transparent;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide some example picture, like you want..?

Comment: @MDKhali do you see the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want only label center and top then apply below CSS on label

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: in order that your solution works I have to add `<ion-col>` but this makes my checkbox items lengthened to the right.

Comment: can you please put your CSS, because i check whats wrong.

Comment: added the secs and the import I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Use this grid with rows and colums instead of ionic grid and see if it works for 
`<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2 ui-inputgroup">`

Comment: If I apply that html I get 8 long checkbox items each on top of the next one and the icon being not in the middle but on the right side. I also wouldn't know which css to apply here.